# Mono and missing references

Tags: .net, linux, mono, .net-4.5, monodevelop

I'm new to .NET and using Mono (great combination I know), and I am having trouble with some missing references from a code developed in Visual Studio.

I would like to know if it is possible to have these libraries for Mono?

```
System.Web.Entity
DevExpress.Web.v14.1
DevExtreme.WebForms.v14.1
Dotnet.Highcharts
System.Web.DataVisualization
System.Deployment
Aspose.Cells
```

Thanks for the help...

Comment: DevExpress is a third-party solution so I guess no: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T184730

Comment: indeed but System.Web.Entity isn't third party...as others in the list. that's why i'm asking

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add a project reference to some missing NuGet packages.

If you have MonoDevelop 4.x or under, go [here](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin) first and follow the instructions to install the NuGet add-in. (If you have version 5.0 or later, then it should come built in already.)

Then, right-click on your References folder and there should be an option to manage/install NuGet add-ins. Click that. Search the names of your packages in the search box, install them, and you should be able to resolve your references.

Comment: it's monodevelop 5.1 so what you propose is automatically done by the IDE.

Comment: I was implying that the NuGet package manager should come built-in, not that the packages that you'll need are automatically installed by the IDE. If you were talking about that, the IDE can only auto-import namespaces from existing references; it does not sift through every package on nuget.org every time it sees an invalid type.

Comment: well, i thought nuget would automatically add them. but in any case, these packages aren't available through nuget it seems.. i decided to run virtualbox with visualstudio..just my luck...